# How can I get a class that takes generic type, to call a method from an instance of that type?

Tags: c#, generics, overriding

I have a base class "Entity" with the following method (I'm not implementing IEquatable, that was a huge headache so I ditched that approach)

```
    virtual public bool Equals(Entity entity)
    {
        throw new Exception("The base Entity.Equals method should never be called");
    }
```

I have several classes that extend Entity.  Each one will implement an Equals method, something like this.

```
    virtual public bool Equals(TestPlan other)
    {
        if (this.TestPlanType.Equals(other.TestPlanType) &&
            this.Name.Equals(other.Name) &&
            this.Description.Equals(other.Description) &&
            this.DatetimeCreated.Equals(other.DatetimeCreated) &&
            this.UserNameCreated.Equals(other.UserNameCreated) &&
            this.Duration.Equals(other.Duration) &&
            this.Scenarios.SequenceEqual(other.Scenarios)) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

I really want to have the input be of type TestPlan instead of Object.  (At least I think I do, I don't want to lose strong typing).

I realize this method doesn't "override" the base class because I made it virtual public instead of public override.

I have a method that takes a generic type that will call .Equals()

```
    public int GetIdenticalEntityId<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        List<T> exitingEntities = LoadEntities<T>();
        foreach (T existingEntity in exitingEntities)
        {
            if (existingEntity.Equals(entity))
            {
                return existingEntity.Id;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The problem is that the exitingEntity.Equals() calls the base class .Equals.

How can I get a class that takes  generic type, to call a method from an instance of that type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override the base `Equals(object other)` method. It's simple enough.

You could even make it mandatory, by declaring this in your `Entity` class:

```
public override abstract bool Equals(object other);
public override abstract int GetHashCode();
```

Now, in your classes, the `Equals` methods would look like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as TestPlan;

    if (other == null)
        return false;

    if (ReferenceEquals(other, this))
        return true;

    return this.TestPlanType.Equals(other.TestPlanType) &&
        this.Name.Equals(other.Name) &&
        this.Description.Equals(other.Description) &&
        this.DatetimeCreated.Equals(other.DatetimeCreated) &&
        this.UserNameCreated.Equals(other.UserNameCreated) &&
        this.Duration.Equals(other.Duration) &&
        this.Scenarios.SequenceEqual(other.Scenarios));
}
```

Now if you want to implement `IEquatable<T>` it will be *really* easy:

```
public bool Equals(TestPlan obj)
{
    return Equals((object)obj);
}
```

You can also do this the other way around:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as TestPlan);
}

public bool Equals(TestPlan obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    // Same code as before
}
```

Oh, and you should implement `GetHashCode` too in order to avoid nasty surprises:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var hash = TestPlanType.GetHashCode();

    hash = (hash * 397) ^ Name.GetHashCode();
    hash = (hash * 397) ^ Description.GetHashCode();
    hash = (hash * 397) ^ DatetimeCreated.GetHashCode();
    hash = (hash * 397) ^ UserNameCreated.GetHashCode();
    hash = (hash * 397) ^ Duration.GetHashCode();
    hash = (hash * 397) ^ Scenarios.GetHashCode();

    return hash;
}
```

This is *really* important. Someone in your team may one day want to use your object as a key in a dictionary for instance. If you properly implement the `GetHashCode` functions from the start you will avoid such traps in your future code. This is a small price to pay today for avoiding big WTFs in the future.

Here you go, it's all you really need.

Comment: What happens if someone passes in the wrong type?  Won't var other = obj as TestPlan throw an exception?  I'm not implementing IEquatable, do I still have to implement GetHashCode()?  What would be the advantage of implementing IEquatable over doing it with just 1 method?  This code has one sole purpose, to check if database entries are equal when replicating.  So its not like we expect people to pass around objects and compare them all of the time.

Comment: @Miebster I'll expand my answer. But for now, `obj as TestPlan` will return `null` if `obj` is not a `TestPlan`.

Comment: @Miebster You don't want to override Equals and not GetHashCode. Some of .Net's classes (like Dictionary) make some assumptions with these 2 that you really don't want to break.

Comment: Should I just call the function something different?  I'd rather not right GetHashCode for each entity.

Comment: @Miebster yeah if you want to have AwesomeEquals instead, nothing prevents you from doing that. However you're clearly just doing Equals, and the price of GetHashCode really isn't that high if you use refactoring tools like ReSharper. I think it does everything for you actually.

Comment: I 100% agree with @GuillaumeCR. And yes, R# generates that boilerplate code for you in no time.

Comment: I'm using VS Express, I don't think R# is an option.  I'll look into getting it sometime but I'll have to write the boilerplate myself for now.

One last thing, will List<Scenario> Scenarios.SequenceEqual hook into my .Equals if I do use the IEnumerable interface?

Comment: @Miebster Yes sir/m'am. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention: IMO `IEquatable<T>` is only useful for value types in order to avoid boxing. It's kinda redundant for classes, but it documents the fact that the class has a custom equality comparison function. `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will pick up your overriden base class methods anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override a function, the arguments must be of the same time. So your TestPlan.Equals should be similar to:

```
override public bool Equals(Entity entity)
{
    TestPlan other = entity as TestPlan;
    if (other == null)
       return false;
    if (this.TestPlanType.Equals(other.TestPlanType) &&
        this.Name.Equals(other.Name) &&
        this.Description.Equals(other.Description) &&
        this.DatetimeCreated.Equals(other.DatetimeCreated) &&
        this.UserNameCreated.Equals(other.UserNameCreated) &&
        this.Duration.Equals(other.Duration) &&
        this.Scenarios.SequenceEqual(other.Scenarios)) return true;
    return false;
}
```